# managing the relationship between Parent and its child content type

Tags: list, development, content-type, site-column, site-contents

I am a bit confused about the relation between Parent and child content type.

Now I want to create a new content type that have the Issue as its parent content type. So how I should be managing the two content types (parent and child) in the following scenarios:-

- If I want to add a new site column to the child content type, should I add it directly to the child content type or I should added to the parent content type?
- If I want to change the “Column Settings” for a field such as if it is optional, required, hidden should I do it at the parent or at the child content type.
- Let say I created 3 issue tracking lists based on the custom content type which i have created and which have the  Issue as it parent content type. Where each issue tracking list will have different values for the Priority site column. So is it a bad practice to modify the Priority values at each list level , where the Priority will have different values at each of the list levels ? Or it is better to create a new Priority site columns for each list. in other word should I always create new site columns or it is better to modify the same site column at the list level ?

Can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 3):

When working with parent/child content types, I do this:
The parent has only the fields that will exist in *all* child content types. Then each child content type only has the fields in it that are needed and are not inherited from the parent. So if your children each have different priority values, then each one would have their own priority field that is unique to their content type.

Example: 2 Content types contain shared field, customer, and each child has a unique field.

Parent content type contains customer field.
Child content type 1 is created from parent and a new column is added into that. 
Child content type 2 is created from parent and a new column is added into that.

Comment: so you mean after creating the new child content type, i will remove the parent columns from it ? but what if i want the parent column to have different setting or values on each of the child content type ?

Comment: also you mentioned "So if your children each have different priority values, then each one would have their own priority field that is unique to their content type." so i need to create a new site column for each of the Priory columns ? or you mean to keep the parent Priority inside the child content type and modify it at the child level ?

Comment: That is how I do it yes, create separate priority fields for each child if they contain different values otherwise I'd use the inherited field from the parent.

Comment: so as i general rule i should not have the parent content type and its child have different values or settings for the same column? also i should not have a site column that have different setting or values at the list level... so for example if i want a Priority field that have different values on each content type or on each list then i need to create a new site column instead of modifying the site column at the list level ? is this correct ?

Comment: based on your edit i should not remove the shared field (the customer) from the child content type,, i though you mentioned that i need to remove any shared fields from the child content type... is this correct ?

Comment: The parent content type is never used in any list, it serves as the conduit to create child content types and make it so that you do not have to recreate each shared field in the children. So the parent is the union of all shared fields, that is all. Each child derived from the parent will automatically inherit the fields of the parent. If that child is not going to use a field, it should not be in the parent.

Comment: and does this apply to the built-in content types ? so if i will not use the "Due Date" field inside the Issue content type,, should i remove it from the parent ? and what if i need it in the future ?

Comment: second question,, now the built-in Issue content type have a column named "Priority" ,, now in my case i will have 4 issue tracking lists ,, where some lists will have different values for the Priority field.. so how i will be managing this ? now i will create a new content type that have the Issue as its parent ,, and the issue tracking lists will be using the child content type, but each list will have different values for the Priority column,, so should i in this case create new child content type for each tracking list (i do not think so)

Comment: , or i should in this case modify the Priority column at the list level ???

Answer (score 2):

The hierarchical relationship allows you to reuse the settings (fields) defined in one content type (parent) in other (child) content types. The hierarchy of content types can be extended to an infinite width and depth, but the best practice is to use 3-level parent-child hierarchy.

[image: Site Content Type structure]

You could read more [best practices on how to manage content types and documents here >>](http://blog.enovapoint.com/post/Sharepoint-Document-Management-Doing-it-Right)

Hope it will make more sence for you to make a right decision in your situation.

Edited acording disscusion: 
You could create general columns in Site collection level and add to CT. Then create a fresh subsite, create other columns you need on this subsite level and add those to list with your site collection columns (CT). Then to save this site as template. And I suspect that all sites created from this site template will have two types of columns: Site collection columns, which you could manage from "backend" and apply modifications; and Site level columns. So subsite admins could modify subsite fields as they need. I think this option would work for your.

Comment: thanks for the link ,, so if i have a Priority drop-down column, but each list will have different values inside the drop-down,, so should i create separate site columns for the priory column ? and what about the Priorty field that is already defined inside the Issue parent content type ?

Comment: Yes, if it is a choise column with different values, you need to create several columns like PriorityA, PriorityB, PriorityC. 
Every field inserted in parent CT are inherited in child content types. So if you need that field you already have, you could leave it, but if it mast be differet in every child CT, you need to remove it from parent and add to child dependint on content type (PriorityA or PriorityB)

Comment: and will these column be on different content types ? so in my case if each of the 4 issue tracking lists will have different values for the Priority column,, then i need to create 4 different content types ?

Comment: Yes, Best it would be like this:
_Issues (field1, field2)
_Issue (inherits _Issues field, plus field3, field 4)
Issue1 (inherits _Issue + PriorityA)
Issue2 (inherits _Issue + PriorityB)

Comment: And on TrackingList1 you add Issue1 content type; On TrackingList2 you add Issue2 and etc

Comment: from your reply i should never do these; 1) Never modify a site column at the list level, instead  i should create a new site column. 2) Never modify a Parent field inside the child content type, instead i should modify the Parent content type or to add  a new column at the child content type ...

Comment: You could do as you wish, but according best practices you shouldn't :) 
It could be troubles in future with creating a site or list templates for reuse, also it will be mass on every list/site. But doing with best practices you have everything in one place to configure and just few seconds to add this to additional list.

Comment: now i want to create a single sub-site + 4 Content Types, and then create 4 lists where each list will be based on a single CT. then i want to save the sub-site as template. After that end users can start creating sub-sites based on the template.. now if end users need to have unique setting for their 4 lists (such as adding unique choices for a drop-down field, chnage if a field is required, optional,etc) ,, what is the best approach i can follow ??,,, the only approach that came to my mind is to allow them to modify the columns and content types at the list level  ,

Comment: but in this case the site collection columns and site collection content types will be out of sync with their list content types and list column ... so is this totally wrong ?can u advice on this ?

Comment: i do not know the case in SP2010,, but on SP 2013 if you modify the content type or the site columns at the site collection level ,, this will affect the underlying sub sites and the sub sites' lists ...

Comment: also inside the subsites all the content types and site columns can not be modified at the sub site level, and they need to be modified from their source ,, which is the site collection. even the content types and site columns at the sub site level will not click-able ... but you can modify them at the sub sites' list level..

Comment: this what i did i saved the sub site as a template,, then i created a new sub site from the template,, now inside the 2 sub sites i can NOT edit the site columns or the site content types,,,, and they can only be edited from their source (the site collection),,, also when i modify the site columns or the site content type from the site collection level ,, this will affect alll the underlying sub sites...

Comment: Oh, yes, I just remember, that CT inheritance brokes then you create subsite from template on different site collection, so it is not your case. if users need to modify some columns to be requered or hidden, they would do that on list level. Or you could prepare different site templates with different options... but it is monkey job... But in the other hand, if you modify some field in the site collection level they would be overriten

Comment: yes this my original question,, to modify the columns and content types at the list level,,, but any modification done to SC will override any modification,, so i should not update any content type or column at the site level because this might override any customization,,, so now i return back to my original questio..

Comment: Also you could create general columns as I said in Site collection level and add to CT. Then create a fresh subsite, create other columns you need on this subsite level and add those to list with your site collection columns (CT). Then to save this site as template. And I suspect that all sites created from this site template will have sitecollection columns, which you could manage from "backend" and apply modifications and  Site level columns. And subsite admins could modify subsite fields as they need. i think this option would work for your.

Comment: ok this also an option, but regarding the shared site collection columns, still subsites admins can modify the site collection columns copy at the list level , because as u know, when you create a sub site, then SharePoint will create a copy of the site collection's CT & fields in the list. so even if i define the shared columns inside the site collection, this will not prevent subsite admins from modifying the list content type copy at the list level. also what might be considered as shared column now, maybe changed in the future, if some subsites requires unique setting or values.

Comment: Then do all columns at subsite level ant every site created from that template will have its own columns.

Comment: so from your replies you want to say that having the CTs & site columns at the site collection is a bad approach is this correct? now if have the CTs & fields at the site collection level, i still have the ability to apply global updates (i might need this on some occasions), and if i inform the site collection admins that they need to uncheck the option "Update all content types inheriting from this type? " when  modifying the CT & field at site collection level , then i should not have any problem or there is not any risk of overiding the list level customization ,,what do u think ?,,

Comment: while the approach  u r proposing will prevent me from doing global updates even if no list level customization were applied to a field ot to a content type???

Comment: having the CTs & site columns at the site collection is a best approach. But as you said some fields could be modified by subsites admins (in subsite level or list level - it doesn't mutch in that case), so I just want to find the more easy to manage solution for you. If you need some field be updated globally, then you need them on site collection level. If you in future modify them without option to update inheritance, what's the point to modify them then?

Comment: the point will be is to provide a new starting point or a new default values for newly added sub sites. also it will be helpful if in the future the management want to standardize certain drop down lists such as the "Status" drop down list, so i can from the SC level do the global update.. i mean this will stay an option i might need in the future ,,, what do u think ?

Answer (score 2):

attempting to answer your questions specifically

- when adding a new column, you'll want to add it to the parent if you want the parent and subsequent children to have the same column. If your parent is an OOTB SharePoint CT, then only add it to your child. I don't recommend modifying SharePoint content types, you never know what Microsoft might do, plus these content types are used across all lists and libraries, even ones you may not see. Inherit from it, and make that new child your new parent for all of your needs.
- Same thing here, dont mess with the parent, make your own parent (inheriting from an OOTB CT) and do what you will
- You can take this two ways: 1) edit the columns in the lists accordingly, no biggie there or 2) create your base CT inherit from issue, then create separate CTs for each use. Its more work but is more flexible, allowing you to reuse the CTs, and easily search and roll up those CTs specifically, if necessary.

Comment: for the third point you mean if i have 4 issue tracking lists and each tracking list need to have different values for the Priority column (different choices inside the srop down),, then what i can do is to create 4 site columns named PriorityA,PriorityB, C & D. then create 4 content types that have their parent as the "Issue" CT,, after that i will leave the build-in Priority as is in the Parent IssueCT. then on each of the child content types i will add the related Priority site columns ? is this what you are proposing ??

Comment: You can either use the same content type in each list, and just change the column values in the list settings
OR
Create 4 content types using the same site column, and change the values within the site content types

No need to create separate columns

Comment: then this leaves me in three options; create 4 new site columns  OR edit the column at the list level OR edit the column at the child content type ? so i am not sure which approach i need to follow? now having 4 site columns means that i can avoid any problem if some one by mistake update the site column at the site collection level,, so in this case any customization at the list level ot at the content type level will get overridden.. ...

Comment: Having 4 separate columns will help protect them from accidental updates as noted, so that may be a good solution if your sites are prone to random acts of change ;)

Comment: thanks for the reply,, so now it is a bad practice if i allow end users to modify the list content type and list site columns at the list level ??. i mean to to allow them to go to list setting and add choices for dropdown column or change the column setting such as optional,required, hidden.. in this case they will have the flexibility of having their own customization for their sub sites,, but on the other hand i will not be able to apply global updates to all the sub sites,,

Comment: ... because if i update a site column or site content type at the site collection level i might end up overriding any customization that have been made at the list level...  so i am 100% confused. also i was thinking that i can create a sub site with 4 lists , where each list have its own content type,and save the subsite as template. then end-users can create sub-sites based on the templete,, this will work,, but how i will be managing the original CTs and the site columns in this case???

Comment: I share your pain. This is a tough spot. If you're going to grant them that level of permission, you're right, you run the risk of them customizing even more, and then pushing changes down run a risk. If all you want them to do is change choice values, use a lookup list instead, one they can then easily manage the values. If it's a switch from required to hidden, then you need to see how your governance is best met. Should that be a support request? Do you want users having that permission level on a list? Maybe a custom script to handle it for you?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i want to grant Project Manager the ability to change the list settings not for all end users, this permission includes modifying dropdown lists, changing column settings such as required or not etc. this permission will be set at the sub site level,, but they will not have the ability to access the columns or the content types from the site collection level, so there is not any risk for them to do a modification at the site collection level.

Comment: so my first question is about allowing Project managers to modify their lists columns and content types at the list level,  while preventing all users even the site admin from modifying any site column or site CT at the site collection level, to prevent overriding any modifications ? does this sound a valid approach, or it is considered a poor design approach ?

Comment: Maybe we can take this "offline" via email, just to not load up this forum. The topic is swayed from your original ask and the moderators may chime in :):) Email me at david.lozzi at slalom.com and we can continue.

Comment: ya i agree with you i send you an email regarding my current approach i am planning to follow,, waiting for your feedback,, thanks